# Append values before and after decimal point Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have numeric fields on form were users can occasionally type a decimal value with  decimal place but no values on one side. 
i.e the intended value to be entered can be 5 or 5.00
but occasionally a user can type .5 OR 5.
so in this case if they have left out values before the decimal place, I would like to add/append the value with 0.5 or if they have left out the values after the decimal place I would like to add/append with 5.00

.5 => 0.5
5. => 5.00

Ideally the input value would then be updated onBlur or when user clicks/tabs away from that field or anywhere else on the page. My quick attempt at this is currently as follows (untested)

```
$('input').on('blur', function () {

  var currentValue = $(this).val();

  var splitNumber = currentValue.split('.');
  var beforeDecimal = splitNumber[0];
  var afterDecimal = splitNumber[1];

  if (beforeDecimal.length < 1)
  {
    //add one zero before decimal
  }

  if (afterDecimal.length < 1)
  {
    //add two zeros after decimal
  }

});
```

Comment: If you have a decimal point, you cannot split by comma.

Comment: yes you are right, that was a typo on my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can just use a combination of `parseFloat` and `toFixed`

```
parseFloat('.5') --> 0.5
parseFloat('5.') --> 5
```

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  
  if(!isNaN(value)) {
     let parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
     
     $('.output').text(parsedValue.toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<span>Output: </span>
<span class="output">
</span>
```

Comment: Although you do risk introducing floating point rounding errors if there are a lot of decimal places.

Comment: @mpen That is always the case. It depends on the number of decimals OP wants it to round to

Comment: Not always. Input was a string. If you keep it as a string there's no need to introduce rounding error. But yes, this is an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example may help you:

```js
  var myNum1 = .5;
  var myNum2 = 5.;

  function pad(num){
 return num.toFixed(2);
  }

  console.log(pad(myNum1));
  console.log(pad(myNum2));
```